# winforms fill datagridview with mysql data

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

I have little problem with `DataGridView` when I try to render MySL data inside the grid.

First, I use [this mysql class](https://github.com/indieteq/c-sharp-mysql-database-class)

Next, I create model classes with methods which hold a MySql query. In that class I am using `DI` to inject `Db` class in to the following:

```
public class Option
{
    private readonly Database db;

    public Option()
    {
        db = new Database();
    }

    public DataTable ListAll()
    {
          return db.query("SELECT * FROM options");      
    }
}
```

Next in the form class I try this `ListAll` method to `bind` and set in `dataSource`:

```
  private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
            Options o = new Options();      
            BindingSource bind = new BindingSource();

            bind.DataSource = o.ListAll();  

            dataGridView1.DataSource = bind;          
  }
```

After build I get :
[image]

Can someone show me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You said this is a winforms app where is the InitializeComponent method call in your MainWindow Contrstructor?  If it is after the datagridview binding code you might move that InitializeComponent before all your binding code.  InitializeComponent actually creates the controls before that method call datagridview1 is null.  Your code in the post is different from your SS.

Comment: Apologies if my edit might have misrepresented what the author meant in certain places.

Comment: it is really necessary to copy all the code? if it is, `InitializeComponent();` is already there belong `dataGridView1.DataSource = o.ListAll();`

Comment: Well I asked because your code snippet is MainWindow_load which insinuates the form load event.  Your Screen shot shows the error on the constructor which is two very different things I want to make sure i understand what is really occurring.  If you go by screen shot you need to initialize component before attempting to set properties of datagridview.  If you go by code snippet it could be something very different.

Comment: Yeah your right. I change positions of methods. I set `Load` method before constructor with 'InitializeConmp`. Now working good

Comment: Excellent glad it was easy fix!